# Removing a bad commit pushed using git

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-commit, git-push

I am working on a project using BitBucket. I have been able to commit/push all my code until one day my vendor was not ignored, not sure why.

In order to fix I had to un-track the vendor folder. Doing that caused my files in the repository being removed because it was not being tracked anymore.

Now every time I need to push something and do a git pull it deletes my entire vendor folder.

**How can  I remove this commit and go back to a good commit?**

Below is my git log showing the merges, etc. I would like to go back to this hash commit(`e5835fa`) which is my good commit before the "untrack vendor directory".

```
* 66ef40d (HEAD, origin/master, origin/HEAD, master) finalized importing players from excel.
* cfa37b3 pushing import players code
* 3a8f272 implemented importing players from excel.
* 9cf59ad implemented importing players
* 188db12 implemented imprting for players oly from excel file
* 72c086a untrack vendor directory
* e5835fa refactoring chart  display
* a5ffd72 fixed offset on duplicate players started import tool for players and  teams.
* 349dfc0 divided the result by 2
* 27e2845 updqted the sql duplicate teams.
* 80b3741 format change.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rollback to the specified commit:

`git reset --hard e5835fa`

Move head:

`git reset --soft HEAD@{1}`

Commit this state:

`git commit -m "Rollback to e5835fa"`

Push the changes (if desired):

`git push`

Comment: But git reset --hard is actually making the branch point to e5835fa. So if you commit after (as indicated in the second instruction), it's not like you are adding a revision on top of where the branch was originally. In fact, if you reset --hard and then you try to commit right after, git will say there's nothing to commit.

Comment: Sorry about that, I left one line out. Updated. Let me know if that doesn't fix your situation.

Comment: mmmm.... but what are you achieving with the updated version? Get the tree of 66ef40d on a new revision that follows e5835fa? I'm not sure what the guy making the question wants exactly. In case the "vendor folder" (whatever that may mean) was added to the project even though it was ignored (for example, with git add -f), what I would do is go back to the revision where it was added and amend it to make it "go away" from the project and then cherry-pick all the following revisions to get back on track.

Comment: @tehp, it worked like charm. Life saver ;). I can go back coding now again. thqnk you very much.